# Define Value range in element using startsWith() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know if there is a shorter way to simplify below line of code indicating possible values of an element that starts with a defined 3 digit numbers.

```
$('#nf-field-168').val().startsWith("010" | "011" | "012" | "013" | "014" | "015");
```

if there's a way to define them as range (ex. 010 - 015) rather than using the vertical bar Operator? Is such method exist?

Comment: The `|` operator doesn't do what you think it does: the code line posted checks if the Vvalue starts with the string "15". Please edit the post to include more technical detail about the problem you are attempting to solve: what kind of element is `#nf-field-168`, is it user entered, what constraints are place on giving it a value, and what you want to check for.

Comment: @traktor, yes, using `|` is not correct, but I think it deserves further clarification. `|` is a bitwise operator, so JavaScript will first cast strings "010", "011", etc. to numbers 10, 11, etc., then do bitwise  "or" (which yields 15), and then convert it back to string "15" to use with `startsWith`. And perhaps the intent was to use the logical "or" (`||`), which would have evaluated to the first value "010", because it is truthy. In any case, the correct answer by @User863 was to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `match()` and regex

```
$('#nf-field-168').val().match(/^01[0-5]/) // returns null if not matched
```

https://regex101.com/r/F8VnaZ/1